# OrientDB Functions Management questions

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to generate some mock data via a function, basically some edges between a "Department" and "Employee" Vertex.

Here is the code:

```
var employees = gdb.command('sql', 'select * from Employee', []);
var departments = gdb.command('sql', 'select * from Department', []);

for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var emp = employees[i];
    var department = departements[Math.round(Math.random()*(departements.length - 1))];
    var e = "create edge employee_belong_dpartement from #" + emp['@rid'] + " to " +  department['@rid'];
    gdb.command('sql',e, []);
}

gdb.commit();
```

Could someone explain me why I can't get this to work ?

When I log  emp['@rid'] I get nothing back, I can't seem to read the "id" or any other value.
Please help me understand what is going on in the console as its hard to debug thanks

Answer (score 1):

employees contains ODocument objects, so to extract fields you should use .field() method. To get the identity ODocument has .getIdentity() method. Example:

```
var e = "create edge employee_belong_dpartement from #" + emp.getIdentity() + " to " +  department.getIdentity();
```

Lvc@